# What are all the Microsoft SQL Server "Table Options"?

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, change-tracking, sqlpackage

I am upgrading a number of identical SQL Server databases via dacpac. Some of the target databases have Change Tracking enabled. So I wish to include `IgnoreTableOptions=true` in the publish profile. If I don't, the dacpac deployment turns off Change Tracking on the tables and we potentially lose some change data information during an upgrade.

However, before committing to using `IgnoreTableOptions=true`, I need to know it will not have any adverse effects on the rest of my database. I would like to know what is all affected by `IgnoreTableOptions`.

i.e. - [The Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tableoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) do not list Change Tracking as one of the official "Table Options". But Change Tracking is affected by the `IgnoreTableOptions` during a dacpac deployment.

I have been unable to locate an online resource that provides a comprehensive list. Querying `sys.tables` is a start. But I don't know which options in `sys.tables` are affected by `IgnoreTableOptions` and which are not.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: See `table_option` part here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Note, some of those also can be controlled by `IgnoreIndexOptions` flag. To ensure that particular set of flags "does not affect the rest of db" - test it by reviewing `Schema compare` results or generating **deploy script** with required set of flags.